# Math Equation in Ticket App Not Formatting Correctly

Tags: swift, xcode

I’m having a difficult time formatting my math equation to calculate and format correctly. When I try to add the child ticket to the total price function, it formats the total price label very oddly. It formats the tickets totals separately instead of together. It has something to do with my function for calculating price.

My total price block of code is as follows:

```
totalPriceLabel.text = String(adultTicket.price * Double(adultTicketsSelected)) + String(childTicket.price * Double(childTicketsSelected))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey, Can you throw some light as to how the formats are different, so that it'll be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

to keep it simple while you get the hang of things, calculate the value first:

```
let price = adultTicket.price * Double(adultTicketsSelected) +  childTicket.price * Double(childTicketsSelected)
```

You could use string interpolation to then convert this to your text:

```
totalPriceLabel.text = "\(price)"
```

but you'd be better using either a number formatter or `String(format:)`

```
totalPriceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", price)
```

I'll let you research the NumberFormatter yourself. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  This is one way to do it, but also through some brute force effort, I have discovered that using 2 strings and adding them together rather than 1 string and adding the double values.  I appreciate the help! Thank you!